# How to check if date is valid (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, error-handling

I have this before_save function:

```
def set_birth_date
    return unless pesel_changed?

    day = pesel[4..5]
    case pesel[2..3].to_i
    when 0..19
      month = pesel[2..3]
      year = pesel[0..1].prepend('19')
    when 20..39
      month = (pesel[2..3].to_i - 20).to_s
      year = pesel[0..1].prepend('20')
    when 40..59
      month = (pesel[2..3].to_i - 40).to_s
      year = pesel[0..1].prepend('21')
    when 60..79
      month = (pesel[2..3].to_i - 60).to_s
      year = pesel[0..1].prepend('22')
    end
      birth_date = Time.strptime("#{day}/#{month}/#{year}", '%d/%m/%Y')
    if birth_date.valid?
      self.birth_date = birth_date
    else
      errors.add(:pesel, I18n.t('activerecord.errors.models.profile.attributes.pesel.invalid'))
    end
  end
```

(Little explanation: Last if condition is not yet included in function. All I want to do is save birth_date if valid, but if it's not valid, I want to add error.) But sometimes it gives me error like this:

```
`strptime': invalid date or strptime format - `12/14/2022' `%d/%m/%Y' (ArgumentError)
```

How can I check if Time.strptime("#{day}/#{month}/#{year}", '%d/%m/%Y') is valid? "valid?" and "valid_date?" don't work.
For months I can do something like this

```
if month / 12 > 0
  <Handling error>
else
  <update>
end
```

But for days... This won't be that easy. Any ideas?

EDIT:
pesel is a string. This function extract birth date from pesel number. Pesel number is 11 digit number, for example:

```
50112014574
50 - year of birth
11 - month of birth
20 - day of birth
14574 - Control number
Those "magic numbers' defines which year someone was born
If someone was born in 19XX, then month number is 1-12.
If someone was born in 20XX, then month number is 21-32 (month number + 20. Example pesel number: '50312014574', which means this person was born 20th November 2050
If someone was born 21XX, then month number is 41-52 (month nubmer + 40) Example pesel number: '50512014574', which means this person was born 20th November 2150 etc.
```

I'm working on existing database and I can't just validate pesel number

Comment: What is the input format for `pesel`? What does this method actually do? What do all those magic numbers mean?

Comment: Why wouldn't the date be valid? I would start from there...

Comment: @spickermann Question edited. More explanation at the bottom.

Comment: @kouroubel Because some users may have entered a random pesel number, which may result in a date like 56/18/<year>

Comment: How about preventing them from entering any number they want by doing some validation on user input?

Comment: @kouroubel I'm working on existing database and I can't just validate pesel number. Existing users still could have invalid pesel number But yes, that is good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot validate the `pesel` numbers in the database first then I would just catch the error and handle it in an `rescue` block.

To do so change

```
birth_date = Time.strptime("#{day}/#{month}/#{year}", '%d/%m/%Y')

if birth_date.valid?
  self.birth_date = birth_date
else
  errors.add(:pesel, I18n.t('activerecord.errors.models.profile.attributes.pesel.invalid'))
end
```

to

```
begin
  birth_date = Time.strptime("#{day}/#{month}/#{year}", '%d/%m/%Y')
  self.birth_date = birth_date
rescue ArgumentError => e
  errors.add(:pesel, I18n.t('activerecord.errors.models.profile.attributes.pesel.invalid'))
end
```

Comment: It does not work. I entered '12195678915' and it saved the new pesel number, but birth_date remained 'nil'

Comment: Did you check if the error was set? Because currently you set the error in `before_save` and not `before_validation` you will certainly pass all validations, then populate the `error` hash but still save the record. Instead, you might want to try calling this method `before_validation`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the year and month, you might want to check if the day is greater than

```
n_days =  Time.days_in_month(month, year)
```

Comment: This could work, but I would have to make an if inside an if. The first if to check if the month exists, and the second if to check if it has that many days. spickerman way is easier and cleaner, but thank you for your answers :)

Comment: It maybe more elegant but how do you know if the date is a realistic one? Any chance someone ending up having birthday on September 31 or February 30?

Comment: Normaly Time.strptime would raise an error 'invalid date or strptime format' :) But I didn't know how to handle invalid date. Now I know :)

Comment: 31 September is still an invalid date...kind of.

Comment: That's what "rescue ArgumentError => e" is for. It will not allow to save that kind of date

Comment: You are right. Just tested it and it works like it should...